# Executing Bind to LDAP instance using .NET LDAPConnection

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I'm trying to execute the binding to an LDAP instance using .NET Objects.
Sorry but this is the first time I fight against this kind of enemy (and hope it will be the last one as well!).

This is what I actually do:

```
LdapDirectoryIdentifier serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(primaryIP, securePort);
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

using (LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials))
{
    try
    {
        //conn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        conn.AuthType = (AuthType)authType;
        conn.Bind();
        Console.WriteLine("OK!!");
    }
    catch (LdapException lex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Errore {lex.ErrorCode}: {lex.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Where:

- **primaryIP** is the name of LDAP instance
- **securePort** is 636
- **username** and **password** are absolutely correct (I've checked them logging in into the intranet)

I've found many examples, and everything seems pretty plain and simple. Anyway I can't make through it.
Tried also with all the AuthTypes available, with no luck.
As said, the user exists because I've been able to log into different apps that use this kind of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it on my own.
The username must be set with the full DN.

Now it works correctly.